# C Dynamic Memory Allocation to void pointer

Tags: c, malloc

I have a function to which I will pass a struct ID and it will return me a string.
I will pass a pointer to store the name string and that pointer will be allocated memory by the function called.

```
int ConvertIDToName(void *id, void *name, size_t *size)
{
    int      status = 0;
    unsigned char *xIDname = "user4.microsoft.com";

    *name = (unsigned char*)malloc(30);
    memcpy(*name, xIDName, *size);

    ...

    return(0);
}

main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct ID_t idObj ={1,5, {0,0,0,0,0,5}};
    unsigned char*      IDName = NULL;
    UINT32          IDNameSize = MAX_CHAR;

    ConvertIDToName(&idObj, &IDName, (size_t *)&IDNameSize);

    return(0);
}
```

The function ConvertIDToName() fails to store the allocated memory address in the void pointer.
I am unable to assign memory in the pointer and it gives me error from 3rd statement of function ConvertIDToName():

```
warning: dereferencing âvoid *â pointer
    test_code.c:683: error: invalid use of void expression
```

What am I doing wrong and how to correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `name` parameter is of type `void *`, and you're dereferencing it using `*name`. What you need to do is use another pointer of type `unsigned char **` inside the function or cast `name` to `unsigned char **` before dereferencing it:

```
/* Use namep instead of name. */
unsigned char **namep = name;

*namep = malloc(30);
memcpy(*namep, xIDName, *size);

...
```

or:

```
/* Use casts everywhere. */
*(unsigned char **)name = malloc(30);
memcpy(*(unsigned char **)name, xIDName, *size);

...
```

**Edit**

As suggested by @WhozCraig, you may also make your function require the `name` to be `void **` instead of `void *`. This will avoid the need for type casting or another variable. It is a great suggestion since `malloc` returns a `void *` and `memcpy` requires a `void *` parameter. Dereferencing a `void **` will yield a `void *` to work with.

Comment: You can use `void**` as well. It, unlike `void *` is strongly typed.

Comment: Thanks Chrono and Craig for the valuable suggestions. The solution resolves the issue. I missed the simple thing of typecasting the void pointer before using it.